# Django-nested-admin urls not loading

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get any sort of nested inline to work with python 3 and django 1.8.

I tried django super-inlines and that didn't really make them nested, they just kinda showed up next to eachother.

I'm currently trying django-nested-admin and I get a page not found error with this pattern search:

^ ^$ [name='browse']

^admin/ ^server-data.js$ [name='nesting_server_data']

browse links to a separate set of urls and this just will not load any admin links.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
import nested_admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('flightdb.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
]
```

Connecting to /admin/ gets a 404 not found error.

Any help with why the page isn't loading or any better way to get nested-inlines to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `r'^'` will match anything that also matches `r'^admin/'`. Django performs the URL matching by starting from the beginning of `urlpatterns` and progresses until it finds the *first* match. So in this case things that were supposed to be in admin are matching `'^'` which is `flightdb.urls` where they won't be found. You could potentially fix this issue by reordering the url's as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('flightdb.urls')),
]
```

Now admin is checked for a match before the rest of the top level urls.

EDIT: I suspect your issues are coming from using "admin" in your url pattern to go to somewhere other than the default Django admin package. I did some searching around in the source of [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin) and in particular came across something here:
https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin/blob/master/nested_admin/options.py in particular have a look at line 275:

```
    context = {
        'title': _('Add %s') % force_unicode(opts.verbose_name),
        'adminform': adminForm,
        'is_popup': (IS_POPUP_VAR in request.POST or
                     IS_POPUP_VAR in request.GET),
        'show_delete': False,
        'media': mark_safe(media),
        'inline_admin_formsets': inline_admin_formsets,
        'errors': helpers.AdminErrorList(form, formsets),
        'root_path': reverse('admin:index'),
        'app_label': opts.app_label,
    }
```

Here there is a call to `reverse('admin:index')`. This needs to resolve to the usual `admin` path in order to work. When you have your url's defined like you do you run into the problem of `admin` now being something other than the default that django-nested-admin is expecting to see.

Perhaps try a different url pattern that is not "admin" such as the one suggested by their documentation:

```
url(r'^nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
```

This way the `reverse` used in the internals of the django-nested-admin package will work.

Comment: Still doesn't help. I'm getting a page not found (404) error so its checking through all the url's and unable to find the correct one. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with using the django-nested-admin package. Sorry for not properly explaining that initially.

Comment: Have you registered the package in your `settings.py` file? Also you really should edit the question to include the package details here, it's highly relevant.

Comment: I did put the package in my settings.py file and mentioned I was using django-nested-admin in the post.

Comment: Ah, the 404 was just the hint I needed to look deeper into this. Check my edit, hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: I'm still getting the 404 error with this it saying it searched this url: ^nested_admin/ ^server-data\.js$ [name='nesting_server_data']

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is what my settings.py and urls.py look like

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'nested_admin',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # ...
]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
    #...
]
```

Now, don't go to yourproject.com/nested_admin but yourproject.com/**admin** .

You still need the include for nested_admin or it won't work.